# How to disable Visual C# activity from appearing in My Recent Documents?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I would like activity in my Visual C# 2008 Express to not appear in My Recent Documents (I use Windows XP). To clarify, when you open a solution or other file in Visual C#, a link to that solution or other file is added to "My Recent Documents". I would like that not to happen.

How can that be achieved?

I know there's a chance this question is better fit for one of SO's sister sites, but my best judgment was that it fits here...

Thanks

Comment: Thinking as a bit of a developer rather than an IT guy. I'm thinking you could write a little app to watch (using FileSystemWatcher) the Recent folder for .cs files and delete them as the OS writes them.

Answer (score 2):

I know there is a away of stopping Windows from updating the list, but I don't believe there is a way to stop it from updating for certain file types.

I way you may be able to do it with is to use batch scripting.

```
cd "C:\Documents and Settings\PROFILE_NAME\Recent"
del *.<C# file extension or other project extensions>
...
del *.<C# file extension or other project extensions>
```

Create the file using Notepad and save it as `<any name>.bat`.

After you work with you C# project you just run this Batch script and it will remove all your evidence from your My Recent Documents folder.

NOTE: If you can't access the *Recent folder* (because it's hidden) try replacing *Recent* with *My Recent Documents*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[link text](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/Uploads/175/VS_MRU_Src.zip)I've added this functionality to [Visual Studio MRU editor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/VSProjectListEditorIII.aspx).
The list of extensions is currently fixed, and it needs to be roughened out.

The new prelimenary executable can be [downloaded here](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/Uploads/175/VSMRU-exe.zip).
... and the Sources, in case you don't trust me ;)

(I'm not sure if I should keep the separate "save" handling - it was a good idea during testing, but otherwise is rather annoying).